# Customised IdentityUserRole primary key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity Provider and EF 6 Code First and I have created a custom `IdentityUserRole` table which has an extra column `OrganisationId`. The custom table is named UserRole.

The table currently has the default primary key of `UserId` and `RoleId`.

I would like to have the OrganisationId column included in the Primary Key of the IdentityUserRole table.

I can see the UserRole table in my database, and it's the one that's being used for the userroles (there's no aspnet_userrole table and the table has data when I assign a role to a user)

I tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
```

But it doesn't show me the OrganisationId property.

So I tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.OrganisationId, x.RoleId, x.UserId });
```

But when I add a migration, both the Up and Down methods are empty.

**Update (some code)**

The IdentityUserRole class:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole, IOrganisationEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext inherits from `IdentityDbContext<User>`

And `User` inherits from `IdentityRebootUser`

**Update 2**

This is the new DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, 
                             IdentityUserLogin, UserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
```

and this is my new User class:

```
public class User : IdentityRebootUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, 
                        Role, IdentityUserClaim>
```

And the Role class:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<string, UserRole>
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> The type 'MyNamespace.Model.Entities.User' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'MyNamespace.Model.Entities.User' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<string, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin, MyNamespace.Model.Entities.UserRole, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim>'

**Update 3**

I got rid of IdentityReboot. I created my own User object which has the following signature:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, 
                        UserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
```

I can now modify the UserRole table to add an extra PK, which is what I wanted.

The problem I have now is, that I cannot use the default UserStore, because when I tell it to use my custom 'User' table, I get the following error:

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyDB.Model.Entities.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.

So I implemented my own version of IUserStore, which is generating the async errors.

If only there was a way to use UserStore with my custom User object, I would be more than happy.

Comment: What does your `IdentityUserRole` class look like? Also, what does your context inherit from?

Comment: I added the relevant code

Comment: OK, so `UserRole` is the object to use though I assume it now makes `IdentityUserRole` redundant? Your context needs to inherit from the full `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>` instead of the basic one.

Comment: Make sure your User class inherits from the right place too: `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, UserRole, IdentityUserClaim>`

Comment: I fixed it by getting rid of IdentityReboot, changing the appropriate classes and implementing my own UserStore

Comment: So it's all working now?

Comment: no :) it's off to the next error: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Maybe i'll just skip the identity provider completely untill there's a stable version

Comment: Identity *is* stable, I've been using it in production for some time now.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  Please see my update above.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks! That was the information I needed. Basically, I had to customize all Identity objects. Can you add is as an answer?

Comment: Great, glad to hear it's working. Very handy for a multi tenanted environment for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to customise all of your identity objects to specify different keys. There are various tutorials online but the best I've found is from [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity).

Essentially you need to make your own version of each object but inherit from the more complex versions. For example, instead of:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ...
}
```

You would do this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, 
CustomUserClaim> 
{ 
    ...
}
```

And repeat for all object including UserStore, UserManager, RoleManager etc.

Comment: @Fraze That's because this has nothing to do with EF Core, it is EF6 only.