# ASP.NET MVC 4 Code-First IdentityUserRole with additional primary key 3-way-relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, automatic-migration

I have been searching the web for weeks in hope of finding a solution to an issue I'm having when using the .NET Identity framework to create my database.

One of the closest related issues i found is this: [Customised IdentityUserRole primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055740/customised-identityuserrole-primary-key)

However I am using automatic migrations, in order to avoid manually specifying Up and Down methods.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an additional primary key in my UserRoles table, which is derived from IdentityUserRoles and the implementation looks like this:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Company")]
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

My OnModelCreating method looks like this:

```
...
public DbSet<UserRole> UserRolesExt { get; set; }
...

protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    // Failed attempt to make property a primary key below:
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(ur => ur.CompanyId).ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
}
```

However, the table ends up looking like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziz0e.png

One thing that got me puzzled is the fact that it is also set as a nullable type, but I have a feeling that is refering to my custom Company class which only contains primitive data types.

The reason why I want this 3-way-relationship for this entity is that my system will contain several users in several companies, where each user can be a member of more than one company, and hereby also individual roles of that user within the given company.

I would if possible, very much like to avoid making my own UserStores and RoleStores etc., which is some of the solutions I've found, since I would like to keep it simple so to say.

An example from one of my classes that does not derive from Identity classes looks as follows and works just as intended:

```
public class UserModule
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Module"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public Module Module { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried fiddling around with various versions of my data annotations in my UserRole class but without any luck. Is there really no way of extending this UserRole class to have an additional primary key, without having to make major customizations?

It should also be noted that if I simply edit the database manually after creation, I am able to make all three properties primary keys and the table works as intended. But I would very much like to know how I can make it work properly so to say.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May if you will specify attribute like `[Key, ForeignKey("Company"), Column(Order = 2)]`. `Order = 2`, because two PK already have been specified at base class - IdentityUserRole and EF will compose all this three PK together. It is only a suggestion. And also remove fluent PK declaration inside OnModelCreating method, it is not needed, because you alreade have property Company at UserRole class.

Comment: Unfortunately this yields the same result, only difference i receive from placing a column tag is that companyId comes in the first column instead, which does not make much sense since I've defined it to be at position 2. I've also tried removing the fluent declaration, and I know it is only required in one place. However, same result :/ I might have to look into custom UserStores etc. It's just annoying when i can fix it manuallly :) But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add an additional column to the `IdentityUserRole` class and have that column be part of the primary key. To do so, you have to slightly modify your `OnModelCreating` method as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .ToTable("UserRoles")
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId, r.CompanyId })
            .HasRequired(r => r.Company).WithMany();
```

This code essentially redefines the primary key to also include the `CompanyId` column and then makes it a required field.

You should also remove the `[Key, ForeignKey("Company")]` attributes from the `CompanyId` property, to prevent the annotations from interfering with the fluent syntax. I don't think the `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");` line is necessary too, you could try removing it.